# How to display data in webi cross table in different format?

Tags: pivot-table, webi

I have the below data

```
| Week | Region | Sales | Profit |
| ---- | ------ | ----- | ------ |
| 1    | A      | 100   | 50     |
| 1    | B      | 150   | 25     |
| 2    | A      | 120   | 80     |
| 2    | B      | 110   | 75     |
```

And I would like to display it as below in crosstab.

```
| Weeks  | 1     | 2     | 1      | 2     |
| Region | Sales | Sales | Profit |Profit |
| ------ | ----- | ----- | ------ | ----- |
| A      | 100   | 120   | 50     | 80    |
| B      | 150   | 110   | 25     | 75    |
```

However, the crosstable in Webi display as below.

```
| Weeks  | 1     | 1      | 2     | 2     |
| Region | Sales | Profit | Sales |Profit |
| ------ | ----- | -----  | ----- | ----- |
| A      | 100   | 50     | 120   | 80    |
| B      | 150   | 25     | 110   | 75    |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating two crosstabs; one with **Sales** and the second with **Profit**.

[image]

Align the Profit crosstab to be right next to the Sales crosstab.

[image]

Next, select either header cell of the Profit crosstab and hide the column.

[image]

That's it.

[image]